# Why testing doesn't detect test.py's syntax errors? and help me fix a bug

Tags: python, django, testing

I wrote a test code as below and it has some bugs, which I can't detect but my teacher said you have missed `self` somewhere in your code. That was like a hint that I couldn't find that. This is my code:

```
def HomeTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        board = Board.objects.create(
            title='Django', description='Django Desc')
        url = reverse('home')
        response = self.client.get(url)

    def home_test_view_status_code(self):
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def home_test_func(self):
        view = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(view.func, home)

    def test_home_contains_link_to_topics_page(self):
        board_topics_url = reverse(
            'board_topics', kwargs={'id': board.pk})
        self.assertContains(response, 'href={0}'.format(board_topics_url))
```

Even if I run `python manage.py test` this code doesn't throw any error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

please help me what I am doing wrong here. where should be `self` keyword? and why?

Then, I went to library and checked to find the bug and by mistake I added a 'p' in `view = resolvep('/')` and without knowing I run `python manage.py test` it showed this result:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Practice\board\src>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

while checking back my code I saw I misspelt `resolve`, here I come upon this question why it didn't throw a syntax error after testing because resolve() was misspelt?
Then I intentionally added an extra 'e' in `self.clieent.get(url)` and again no errors? 
Please help me understand this
Thank you so much

edit: my test file is named tests.py and it is in board directory app! there is **init**.py file as well.
[image]

I then renamed that to test_board.py and ran the test. It says `ran 0 tests`? what is wrong?

Comment: Well your teacher duped you because the reason it's not throwing a syntax error because it is not running any tests as everyone has stated, not because of any `self`. If there's something missing you'll find out after the tests are up.

Comment: First, I ran a test
Second my teacher didn't dupe me
Third my file name is test.py within my app directory and I just renamed that to test_board.py and i get same results
@lucasgcb

Comment: A misspelling wouldn't throw a syntax error anyway, that would be a NameError.

Comment: @Noor The output `Ran 0 tests` disagrees with you. First get a test to run before trying to debug it, your problem lies elsewhere. Start fresh and read the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got no errors because you ran no tests. Your test filenames must start with `test` like `test_something.py` and the folder needs to have a `__init__.py` file.

More information about how django discover tests to run here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Comment: `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s` means no test was ran and that's why you can't see any failure due to bad syntax/typing errors

Comment: Thank you Marcelo, I just edited my post. Can you please see that. I renamed my test file still not working.

Comment: You are missing a `__init__.py` file in the folder. Also added this information to my response to help other people having the same issue. Please let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

Read the doc @Marcelo linked.

1. Check your test-file filename. (Does it match the django necessary name scheme?)
2. Check your test-file location. (Can it be discovered? Is it in a module? Does a `__init__.py` exist?)
3. Enjoy your tests, or rather...fixing them

Your output **HAS** to change to something along these lines:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in ?.???s

OK
```

(The above output is only true after you've fixed the errors in your tests. But those errors aren't responsible for django not discovering them)

Suggested file structure for many tests:

```
+<project_name>
|--+<project_name>
|--+<app_name>
   |--+tests
   |  |-- __init__.py
   |  |-- test_<general_topic>.py
   |--+templates
...
```

Minimal example:

```
+<project_name>
|--+<project_name>
|--+<app_name>
   |--+templates
   |-- tests.py
...
```

Minimal example requires your test code to be in tests.py. The file structure for many tests requires your test code to be in the `test_*.py` files and STILL have its functiones named `test_*`.

Is your app added to your projects `settings.py`?

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    <app_name>,
]
```

Comment: Edited the answer to have more information about test location, naming, and mentioned the potential settings issue.

Comment: Thank you Bloodmallet, already gave a thumb up for your answer. I appreciate it. God bless you